# Extract string from text of fixed length based on keyword

Tags: php, search, center, keyword

I tried and tried but I'm stumped. Suppose I have the following scenario:

```
$string = "Jenny's garden is one of the best in town, it has lush greens and colorful flowers. With what happened to her recently, she could use a new sprinkler system so that she does not have to over exert herself. Perhaps Joel can sell that extra bike to raise money or perhaps put up a garage sale.";

$keyword = "recently";

$length = 136;

// when keyword keyword is empty
$result = "Jenny's garden is one of the best in town, it has lush greens and colorful flowers. With what happened to her recently, she could use a (snip)";

// when keyword is NOT empty
$result = "(snip)it has lush greens and colorful flowers. With what happened to her recently, she could use a new sprinkler system so that she does not h(snip)";
```

What I'm trying to do is get an excerpt of string as shown on $result possibly centering the first occurrence of a keyword (if it exists). I'm baffled how to achieve this in php using substr and strpos. Help?

Comment: And [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I have tried several methods but I'm not good at calculations AT ALL and that's an understatement. I've been trying to find the string position and then subtracting it from the half of length then running it through sub string. That yielded the results I wanted for some paragraphs but for many that had $keyword towards the end the extracted string was so short. Since the answer by Adam is flawless I dare not spread around my terrible coding practices. However, believe me I tried. I'm not a a person to jump in and have others do my work for me. I simply couldn't grasp the logic behind it.

Comment: Providing all that information in the original question will help you get more answers quicker.

Comment: Didn't think about that, will remember next time =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you need:

```
if ($keyword != "") {
    $strpos = strpos($string, $keyword);
    $strStart = substr($string, $strpos - ($length / 2), $length / 2);
    $strEnd = substr($string, $strpos + strlen($keyword), $length / 2);

    $result = $strStart . $keyword . $strEnd;
}
else {
    $result = substr($string, 0, $length);
}
```

Here is the test code I used:

```
<?PHP
$string = "Jenny's garden is one of the best in town, it has lush greens and colorful flowers. With what happened to her recently, she could use a new sprinkler system so that she does not have to over exert herself. Perhaps Joel can sell that extra bike to raise money or perhaps put up a garage sale.";

$keyword = "recently";

$length = 136;

if ($keyword != "") {
    $strpos = strpos($string, $keyword);
    $strStart = substr($string, $strpos - ($length / 2), $length / 2);
    $strEnd = substr($string, $strpos + strlen($keyword), $length / 2);

    $result = $strStart . $keyword . $strEnd;
}
else {
    $result = substr($string, 0, $length);
}

echo $result;
?>
```

And here is the result that was echoed:

*it has lush greens and colorful flowers. With what happened to her recently, she could use a new sprinkler system so that she does not have to*

EDIT: Fixed a couple bugs in my code...

NOTE: This will dispaly a $result that is 136 characters + the length of the keyword.  If you want it to only be 136, add `$length = 136 - strlen($keyword);`

Comment: Adam you are a genius, I got close but it only worked on keywords towards the start of the string. I simply didn't understand the logic of it all. It never occurred to me to work on the start and end separately and joining them in. Works like a charm!!